# redirect input from keyboard like device to background process in windows environment

Tags: c#, redirect, windows-7, keyboard, stdin

I use simple RFID reader device which connected to PC with usb cable and identified as keyboard like device.
I want to read input from this device by my application but it is running in background i.e. other application is in focus.
How can I redirect stdin to my application in windows 7 environment?
I can't change focus to my application
I can't make change in front application (e.g. catch stdin and send it to my application via pipe etc.)
My application is written in C# but I can rewrite it to Java / C 
The PC runs Win 7 OS.

Thanks
y

Comment: I *think* the phrase you want to search on is "keyboard hook".

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

I have connected a normal **Keyboard** and a **Card Reader** via USB to my computer.
Both devices write to the windows keyboard buffer.

I want to **redirect** the input of the Card Reader to another application or file and **remove it from the keyboard buffer** (so that this input will not show up in any editor).

What I know / Prerequisites:

- The input of the Card Reader only contains hexadecimal letters (0-9, A-F) and is finished by a newline.
- The Card Reader input will be received "on-block", this means between two received letters there are only a few milliseconds
- It is not possible for a human to enter two or more numbers within less than 70ms
  (I have tried it)

What I do:

- I listen to the keyboard buffer and take out every single input letter/key. Any input which is not 0-9 or A-F will be put back to the keyboard buffer immediately.
- If a input 0-9 or A-F comes up I will store it in a string buffer (it might be from the card reader)
- If there is no further input for more than 70ms and there are at least 4 Bytes containing 0-9 or A-F in the buffer, then I assume/know it was from the Card Reader and use it in my own way. These Bytes have been already taken out of the keyboard buffer.
- If there are only one/two/three letter(s) 0-9/A-F in my buffer, then after 70ms they will be put back to the windows keyboard buffer. While typing you can't realise that "some" letters show up a little postponed for a human being.

Here my program (written in the script language [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)):

**KeybRedir.ahk**

```
; KeybRedir
; Programmiert von Michael Hutter - Mai 2018

#NoEnv ;Avoids checking empty variables to see if they are environment variables
#SingleInstance force
Process, Priority, , Normal
#Warn All

SaveKeyList=

0::
1::
2::
3::
4::
5::
6::
7::
8::
9::
+A::
+B::
+C::
+D::
+E::
+F::
Return::
{ ; If one of these characters was typed => take it out of windows key buffer...
    if A_ThisHotkey = Return
        Hotkey:=Chr(13)
    else
        Hotkey:=A_ThisHotkey
    SaveKeyList = %SaveKeyList%%Hotkey%
    SetTimer , DoKeyPlay, 70 ; Wait 70ms for another key press of charlist (re-trigger the timer in case it already runs)
}
return

DoKeyPlay:
    SetTimer , , Off
    SaveText:=RegExReplace(SaveKeyList, "\+", "")
    StringReplace, SaveText, SaveText, `r, , All
    if StrLen(SaveText) < 4 ; Accumulated text size < 4 letters => normal key input
    {
        SendPlay %SaveKeyList% ; put captured text back in windows key buffer
    }
    else ; Now we have the input of the card reader
    {
        SplashTextOn, , , %SaveText% ; Do something with the input or the card reader ...
    }
    SaveKeyList=
    SaveText=
    SetTimer , SplashOff, 2000
return

SplashOff:
    SplashTextOff
    SetTimer , , Off
return
```

You can compile this script to a exe file (327KB) using the [Autohotkey Compiler](https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=16061).